# ipysheets modify layout: wrap text, column width

Tags: python, width, jupyter, spreadsheet

I am using ipysheets for displaying an interactive sheet in jupyter.

I am following the documentation:
https://readthedocs.org/projects/ipysheet/downloads/pdf/latest/

I just can not figure out how to change the layout of a ipysheet once created.

I would like to have a particular width of columns and make possible that the text is wrapped with respect to the content of a particular column (i.e. force line breaks within the cells if the text is too long)

```
import ipysheet as ip
import pandas as pd
API_link_to_data='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenfly/opsd/master/opsd_germany_daily.csv' 

energyDF = pd.read_csv(API_link_to_data)
energy_ip = ip.sheet(ip.from_dataframe(energyDF))
energy_ip
```

When printing out energy_ip (an ipysheet table object) I would like to be able to fix the width (in pixels or how ever) of the columns.

Nevertheless it looks like there is no such property:

```
ipysheet.easy.column(column, 
    value, 
    row_start=0, 
    row_end=None, 
    type=None, 
    color=None, 
    background_color=None, 
    font_style=None, 
    font_weight=None, 
    style=None, 
    choice=None, 
    read_only=False, 
    numeric_format=’0.000’, 
    date_format=’YYYY/MM/DD’, 
    renderer=None, **kwargs)
```

any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

would do the following, hope it answers your question :

```
import ipysheet as ip
import pandas as pd
import ipywidgets as w 


API_link_to_data='https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jenfly/opsd/master/opsd_germany_daily.csv' 

energyDF = pd.read_csv(API_link_to_data)
energyDF['comment'] = 'this column will have line breaks'

energy_ip = ip.sheet(ip.from_dataframe(energyDF))
# set column widths
energy_ip.column_width = [10,10,5,5,5,10]
energy_ip.layout = w.Layout(width='500px',height='100%')
for k,c in enumerate(energy_ip.cells):
    c.style['textAlign']='center'
    c.send_state()

energy_ip
```

Comment: # This helped me a lot:
sheet.column_width = [10,10,5,5,5,10]

Answer (score -1):

You will need to create style in order to achieve this.
Try with style={'width:50px'}

Comment: Quite close, but not yet there. energy_ip.easy.column(style={'width:50px'}) does not work. energy_ip.easy.column(style={'width':'50px'}) neither.

Comment: energy_ip.column(3,[1,2,3,4,5],style={'width':'50px'}) neither. Changes the values of the first 5 elements of column 3, but the style does not change. the result is the same with style={'width':'50px'} than with style={'width':'5px'}

Comment: This answer needs to be a little more specific, as expressed by @JFerro.